# Webpage scrolling stuck while loading iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am working on website of games. When I load inner page which contains an `iframe`, when user scrolls down or up while loading the page then the page gets stuck for sometime. This happens only on page which contains `iframe`.

I search lot for this but did not got any solution.

I dont know but this problem might cause when iframe starts loading until finishes it.

I tried replacing `iframe` with `embed` tag and tried loading iframe after page load but both doesn't work for me.

Iframe/embed code I am using directly as

```
<iframe id="game-loader-iframe" src="<?php echo $game_detail['game_iframe_code'];?>" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

> OR

```
<embed id="game-loader-iframe" src="<?php echo $game_detail['game_iframe_code'];?>" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Below code I am using to load iframe after page load

```
<script>
        $(function() {
          $('<iframe />').attr('src', "<?php echo $game_detail['game_iframe_code'];?>")
            .attr('width', "100%")
            .attr('height', "100%")
            .appendTo('#player'); 
        });
    </script>
```

Does anyone know the solution, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for more clarification, can you share the code?

Comment: It is hard for people to help you without the code for your entire page because it makes it difficult to reproduce your bug.

Comment: @Trobol I cant share the entire code. Source url consist html5 game and loads in iframe.

Comment: It seems like the game is causing the page to lag, does the page lag while loading if you remove the part that loads the game?

Comment: When I commented iframe tag then scroll does not stuck. And my boss suggessted load the game using javascript instead of iframe by looking some other sites, but I don't know how to convert iframe to javascript.

Comment: Don't remove the iframe, remove the javascript you wrote above. I believe that the issue is with the way the game runs so no matter how you load it the page will stutter.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your time buddy.